# How to prevent Wifi in off state

Tags: android, wifi

My network application do not want the WiFi state of device going to be off.

As in setting page have option under advanced to select the radio as always keeping the WiFi enable as screen go off.

I want to do the same thing programmatically, even i tried at starting take the WiFi lock but as soon as screen go in off state the WiFi went into off state.

How to achieve programmatically to keep the WiFi active?

Answer (score 1):

use a wifi [lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html) of type [WIFI_MODE_FULL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#WIFI_MODE_FULL)
or [WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF).